# Unable to run Solr on Azure Web Apps

Tags: java, azure, solr, azure-web-app-service

I'm unable to get solr (6.3.0) to run on Azure websites.  Specifically, it seems to be failing to detect the java version when doing the following

```
"D:\Program Files\Java\zulu8.17.0.3-jdk8.0.102-win_x64\bin\java" -version   2>&1  | findstr /i "version"  1>javavers
type javavers
set /p JAVAVEROUT=<javavers
@REM app_data\bin\solr.cmd start -f -V -p %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

When run from the kudu console, this code runs without error and `JAVAVEROUT` is set as expected.  However when run through the http platform handler, it fails on the last line as shown below

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot>"D:\Program Files\Java\zulu8.17.0.3-jdk8.0.102-win_x64\bin\java" -version      2>&1  | findstr /i "version"   1>javavers 

D:\home\site\wwwroot>type javavers 
openjdk version "1.8.0_102"

D:\home\site\wwwroot>set /p JAVAVEROUT= 0<javavers 
The handle could not be opened
during redirection of handle 0.
```

Any ideas why this fails in the platform handler, but works through the kudu console?

For reference, below is the web.config I'm using.  (Start.cmd is the batch script at the begining of this post.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <clear />
            <add name="httppPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform processPath="d:\home\site\wwwroot\start.cmd" 
            startupTimeLimit="1"
            stdoutLogEnabled="true"
            stdoutLogFile="d:\home\LogFiles\httpPlatformStdout.log"
            />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure what the root cause as to why `solr.cmd` fails in azure websites, but applying https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/pull/113 works around the issue as it removes the code that was causing `solr.cmd` to fail on startup